# „im Beibemerk“ statt „nebenbei bemerkt“

Tags: word-choice, idiom

I came across „im Beibemerk“ used as „nebenbei bemerkt“ today.

Could not find it in any dictionary. How common is it?

Example:
Es regnet heute. Im Beibemerk ist es dieses Jahr so trocken wie noch nie gewesen.

Comment: Es ist so ungewöhnlich, dass ich fragen möchte: Wo ist es Dir denn begegnet? Literatur, mündliche Rede, in welcher Region?

Comment: Mündliche Rede, not too formal context. It didn’t stand out in my perception. Did you hear it before?

Comment: Nein, noch nie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put some numbers on how common or rather uncommon it is, a strict Google search yields "about 11 results", two of which are your questions on germanSE and on toprespuestas.

One result dates back to an old newspaper of 1872 and other results seem to be antiquated as well. It appears to have been used in Bavaria.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use 'nebenbei' and it seems to be the more 'common' use of the meaning you are trying to express.

To answer your question more specifically, 'im Beibemerk' seems to not be as common.

Cheers!

Comment: So ‚im Beibemerk’ is certainly legit… interesting. Regarding my example: Is there a special meaning to it or would you use it differently?

Comment: @xamf toungue-in-cheek use case: if you want to appear pompous and try to impress with your intellectually superior attitude. (Hey! I know a word you have never used before!) Legit, it is. But not modest.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

How common is it? I have never heard it (which does not mean too much) and as you say, one cannot find it in any dictionary. Thus I conclude it is an unusual phrase although a Google search gives a quite a number of hits. However, its origin remains unclear. Perhaps it is a regional thing or somebody wanted to create a new phrase just as an "eyecatcher" in a text. I would not recommend to use it though certainly each reader would understand the meaning.

**Update:**

My Google search gave 46 hits. It seems that "Beibemerk" is sometimes used as a variant of "Anmerkung". This has a slightly different meaning than "nebenbei bemerkt". Examples:

[1](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/welche-ueberwachungskamerahersteller-ruesten-ihre-produkte-mit-unsichtbaren-infrarot-schweinwerfern-aus).

> Schau in das Datenblatt der Kamera-Hersteller.
> Im Beibemerk: gute Kameras für diesen Zweck sind ...

[2](https://www.popsike.com/3-LP-Box-George-Harrison-All-Things-must-pass-NM/320645518165.html).

> Beibemerk, einige der LP`s deren Auktionen am 24. + 26.01. auslaufen, standen Jahre auf dem Speicher ...

Moreover most hits refer to old newspaper articles (mainly from the 19-th century) which could indicate that it is an outmoded expression. The [newest article](http://library.fes.de/magdeburg/pdf/1927/1927-032.pdf) dates from 1927.

In some cases also a verb "beibemerken" is used.  See [here](https://www.bavarikon.de/object/bav:BSB-MDZ-00000BSB11032294?p=976&cq=m&lang=de):

> ... und von jetzt an nur von mir um die beibemerkten herabgesetzten Nettopreise zu beziehen: (Mit 25 % Rabatt gegen baar; franco Leipzig)

Comment: Did you google for `Beibemerk` or `"Beibemerk"`?

Comment: @infinitezero For Beibemerk.